# How does Firebase Analytics calculate active users in the last 30 days?

Tags: firebase-analytics

I have a small app that uses firebase analytics. When I look at the "User activity over time chart", this is what I currently see:
[image: chart]

This looks really weird to me. How can the number of active users in the last 30 days drop to 0 even though I clearly have 1 day active users within that time span?